# Examining TCP traffic from an iOS device

Tags: ios, ipad, tcp, packet-sniffers, sniffer

Is there an app or clever way to check TCP:IPv4 traffic for a host:port on iOS devices?  Users will be connecting to a device with an iOS app, and if there is an existing way to sniff or otherwise log TCP (and any IP traffic) on an iPad that would be super useful.  We could eventually add this into the app, but it seems like there has got to be a nice app for inspecting a network... e.g. some of the functionality of wireshark, socat, and nmap.  I don't seem to be able to use the right search terms in the app store and I'm also wondering if there is a way to do this in the Safari browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using iTelnet and turning off all the login scripts.  That will connect to any ip:port with TCP.